# Estilo citação: "(Autor, Data)" para "Autor (Data)"

Tags: latex

Estou usando *abntcite*. Gostaria de saber como alterar o estilo de apenas algumas citações de `(Autor, Data)` para `Autor (Data)`. Eu tentei usando `\citeauthor{chave}`, mas não funcionou. Obrigado.

Comment: Creio que a pergunta está clara sim, só não sei se pode ser considerada como conteúdo relacionado a programação. @samuel.nascimento.junio, dê uma olhada [nesse link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/latex-br/VnEE9MxAenE), veja se ele te ajuda em algo.

Comment: Obrigado @Mateus!
Gostaria de saber como alterar a seguinte string
<code>year empty$ 'skip$ {" " * year *}</code>
Para ela me retornar (year).
Simplesmente não encontrei como ainda.

Comment: o @LucasNunes te deu uma resposta, talvez seja o que você procura. Como você é novo por aqui, seria legal dar uma olhada no [tour] para saber como funciona o [pt.so], caso você ainda não saiba.

Comment: Obrigado @Mateus, mas não me ajudou. A resposta dele está correta, no entanto, eu recebi um projeto montado onde arquivos fazem referência a outros arquivos. Eu encontrei a função que faz a saída para \citeonline{} e ela aparece no seguinte formato:  "Autor, Data" em vez de "Autor, (Data)". Ainda não é o que eu preciso.

Comment: você tentou alterar (faça o backup do arquivo antes) o código que você postou acima para `year empty$ 'skip$ {"(" * year * ")" *} if$`? Você pode também dar uma olhada [nesse link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71372/elementary-introduction-to-creating-bibtex-styles), ele fala algumas coisas sobre `BibTeX styles`. Se não der certo, minhas sugestões se esgotaram =/

Comment: Tem um site da SE específico para LaTeX. [Link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Olá @mutlei e demais colegas. O Tex/LaTeX é uma ferramenta que gera documentos, mas usa uma linguagem com sintaxe própria e o equivalente a um compilador. Existem até mesmo pacotes que permitem utilizar decisões lógicas e laços de repetição. Constantemente surgem comentários que julgam o assunto fora do escopo, mas [as perguntas têm sido bem aceitas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex). Além disso, a existência de uma alternativa em inglês não me parece argumento para definir como fora do escopo, pois o próprio SOPT advém da existência de pessoas que preferem o Português. :)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar:

```
\citeonline{ID_DO_AUTHOR}.
```

Isso gera:

```
 Fulano (2014)
```

E é útil também para situações como:

```
 Segundo \citeonline{ID_DO_AUTHOR} o sistema ...
```

---

Se for o caso, você também pode informar a página da citação assim:

```
\citeonline[p.~20-22]{ID_DO_AUTHOR}.
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu sugeriria:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

(havando várias opções: sectionbib, square, etc). Ao citar usa:

```
\citep{jon90} for a parenthetical citation (Jones et al., 1990),
\citet{jon90} for a textual one, as Jones et al. (1990).
```

Ver detalhes em CTAN://macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf